# Unable to install meteor 1.3 on win 8.1 laptop

Tags: meteor

I'm a newbie, but have been able to install and program in Meteor/mongodb/iron router etc and deploy to Galaxy over the last few months on Meteor 1.2.1 running on a win 10 desktop.  Fortunately I haven't updated it, because when I tried to install on a Win 8.1 laptop I ran into many problems and am completely stuck.  Here are the problems:

1. running "meteor create "  creates, even for sample projects set up by meteor, javascript files that have "import" statements…and Webstorm says the current version of javascript doesn't support them.
2. When I try to execute "meteor run" in a project directory,  it stalls forever trying to download meteor-tool@1.1.9... however, that doesn't happen if I first do "meteor npm install"  in one of the sample project directories.   It will run, but it then I think it dies trying to compile the "import" statements (I'll paste some of the console errors below).   They are not very revealing to me, to say the least.
3. Not as important, but after the install, Meteor can't recognize my meteor dev account, and any new ones I create get forgotten for a subsequent reinstall, even though they use up an email address each time.  "Login failed" in an alert statement is the only explanation.

I have searched hard for these various errors (found one unhelpful one on the stall problem), but I think the bigger problem is all the magic configuration items that I have no idea are correct or not.  I have of course uninstalled and reinstalled; I've rebooted; I've used webstorm 11, and compared webstorm's config with the one running on the win 10 machine as far as libraries, all the same.

I'd appreciate any help-- I'd like to continue developing on a trip with the laptop, and someday I will have to update Meteor to 1.3, though I dread it.

```
C:\Users\bardrichmond\to-dos>meteor run
[[[[[ C:\Users\bardrichmond\to-dos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While loading plugin `compileTemplatesBatch` from package `templating`:
   module.js:338:15: Cannot find module
   '../modules/es6.object.get-own-property-descriptor'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\bardrichmond\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.7\plugin
.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_module
s\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor-ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\
core-js\es6\object.js:12:1)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\bardrichmond\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.7\plugin
.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_module
s\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor-ecmascript-runtime\server.js:1:1
)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at npmRequire (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1665:14)
   at Module.useNode (packages/modules-runtime.js:453:20)
   at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:157:20)
   at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16)
   at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.ecmascript-runtime.runtime.js
   (packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:24:18)
   at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:158:9)
   at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16)
   at packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:2832:15
   at packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:2845:3


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\bardrichmond\to-dos>
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem, you describe it very well, good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Navigate to "C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Local.meteor\packages"
2. Delete the issue package folders entirely (templating, ecmascript,
   standard-minifier-css, coffeescript)
3. Run your terminal window.
4. Make sure your terminal is in the correct directory where your App
   is located.
5. Run "meteor update"
6. Run "meteor" and wait patiently as it attempts to download the
   missing packages, this might take a while.

credits on: [github meteor issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6609)

Comment: no problem! Glad it worked for you too, had my head spinning around with this issue as well

Comment: And this worked for me too!  I deleted those four files and ran meteor, and eventually it appeared to have fallen back to Meteor 1.2.1 (which is fine with me):   "=> Meteor 1.2.1: Bug fixes and improvements for Meteor 1.2, including new ES2015
polyfills. See History.md for details."

Anyway, THANKS rdk!

Comment: @Bard after deleting the files run "meteor update" and it will go to meteor 1.3, you should then be able to run the app on meteor 1.3 version as well.

Comment: Thanks rdk.  I didn't want to for fear of the editor I'm using (Webstorm) not being able to error-check ECMAscript2015, but it turns out there's a switch in that program to allow it.

Comment: @Bard can you mark this as the correct answer, so other people know this is the solution