# Meteor stopped working

Tags: meteor

I was working on a meteor project (version 1.2, React installed) when suddenly a spew of errors appeared in the command prompt.  I could no longer start the server.  Entering 'meteor' and nothing happened.  I then uninstalled meteor completely and reinstalled (now version 1.3).  The problem persisted. The only command I could get to work was 'meteor --help'. Even doing a new create (meteor create newapp) did nothing. The command line carriage returned and did nothing.  I'm running under windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have ran into issues when updating to meteor 1.3. Possible duplicate answered here:

[Unable to install meteor 1.3 on win 8.1 laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322511/unable-to-install-meteor-1-3-on-win-8-1-laptop/36323783#36323783)

Comment: looked at this posting.  Tried its solution, but not applicable.  I can't even run 'meteor update'.  It just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. It's a problem from the 1.3 release on Windows. 
In the [github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6609) issues you can find the solution they found to solve this temporarily; what you have to do is this:

Delete the following folders from    *C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local.meteor\packages*

- templating, templating-tools, ecmascript, standard-minifier-css. But some people mention having to delete extra folders too <-- emphasis on this

Then open the console as administrator and run meteor in the folder where your app is, so it starts downloading the missing packages you deleted.

This would be enough for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, emmaielle, for your response.  Unfortunately, this doesn't do it.  I believe it's not a 1.3 release problem, but rather a windows 10 issue.  I was running v 1.2 when the command prompt filled with error messages and I was unable to restart the server (by typing just 'meteor').  When I decided to uninstall and reinstall Meteor, the install was with v1.3, but to no avail.  I'm wondering if there's a registry entry for Meteor that has to be removed during the uninstall process.  Do you know?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about it being a Windows 10 issue, because I was running it from Windows 10 as well, and this solved it. Did you make sure to completely delete those files? Because some of them have names that are too long to be deleted, and windows suggests to move them first, change their names to a shorter one, and then delete it. Maybe those files weren't really deleted in your case. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I had performed those exact steps earlier to no avail.  I just gave it another try, though (with a fresh install of v1.3).  Logging into my project folder and typing 'meteor' - nothing.  Just hangs.  Backing out of that folder, I tried a fresh 'meteor create'.  Nothing.  Can't even do a 'meteor --version'.  The only command I can get to respond is 'meteor --help'.  That's why I thought that during the uninstall (of the corrupted 1.2 version) there were some residual files - perhaps in the registry - that needed to be deleted.

Comment: Create new windows user and look what happens.
Try execute meteor install "As administrator".

Comment: Created new user.  Same problem.  Running as administrator.